# Django tests - a test in classA fail when i run classB (which is subclass of classA)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have a test suite with multiple classes - ClassA and ClassB. ClassB is a subclass of classA and when I run classA tests, they all pass. However when i run ClassB, a classA test fails. I'm not sure how or why this is happening.

```
 class ClassA(TestCase):
      def test1(self):
            # run test

      def test2(self):
            # run test


class ClassB(ClassA):

      def test3(self):
            # run test

      def test4(self):
            # run test
```

> python manage.py test app.tests.test_views.ClassA

```
all pass
```

> python manage.py test app.tests.test_views.ClassB

```
FAIL: test1 (app.tests.test_views.ClassA)
Test 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/test_views.py", line 1435, in test1
    obj.evidence, "This is the evidence entered by user."
AssertionError: 'Generic evidence' != 'This is the evidence entered by user.'
    - Generic evidence
+ This is the evidence entered by user.
```

This is obviously a simplified example, and I know the best thing would be to not subclass ClassA in ClassB, however in my actual code there are ClassB tests that require some methods of ClassA. I understand this would be better handled with fixtures, but this is how it is set up at the moment and it would be a big revamp to rework this.

My understanding is that all ClassA tests are run when I execute ClassB test method, as it is subclassed:

> python manage.py test app.tests.test_views.ClassA

```
runs test1 and test2
```

> python manage.py test app.tests.test_views.ClassB

```
runs test1, test2, test3 and test4
```

However, I thought each time a test was run, the database was emptied and re-instated. Therefore why would test1 pass when running ClassA, but fail when ClassA tests are run as part of ClassB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're figuring out, repetition is good in tests. Abstracting tests only complicates debugging and when something breaks, the last thing you want to do is debug your test before you can debug your problem.

That said, if you have shared functionality, make sure they don't generate data and  if they do that they clean up after themselves. In your oversimplified case that's not obvious, but if you share setUpClass or setUpTestData or fixtures class attributes, you're likely to run into trouble.